# Webview background for directly loaded image with transparency

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm loading a transparent PNG directly into my webview:

```
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
// let's use testing image 
webView.loadUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png")
```

Sadly, the background of webview is dark and I'm unable to change to white in no way.

I've tried `setBackgroundColor()` and `setBackgroundResource()` directly before `loadUrl` and in `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` without any luck.

I've also tried to make the webview transparent to "draw" the white background by the layout, doesn't work either.

[image: black webview]

Comment: Have you use this `mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. Though, ideally I'd like to a white background, not a transparent :)